# rail why get time differs from the time to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when i selected row from db i get 16:26:03:
database=# select posts.created_at from posts where id = 1;

```
         created_at         
----------------------------
 2012-04-10 16:26:03.538866
```

but from code

```
logger.info Post.find(1).created_at

2012-04-10 12:26:03.538866
```

Why get time differs from the time to the database?

Comment: Random language neutral guess: your timezone is +4 (or -4) and someone did not handle UTC to local conversion correctly throughout code.

Comment: Thanks. i found answer. it is config config.time_zone from environment.rb

Answer (score 2):

i found answer.

file:

```
environment.rb
```

line:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```